# Using subprocess wait() and poll()

Tags: python, subprocess

I am trying to write a small app that uses the `subprocess` module.

My program calls an external Bash command that takes some time to process. During this time, I would like to show the user a series of messages like this:

> Processing. Please wait...
>   The output is foo()

How can I do this using `Popen.wait()` or `Popen.poll()`. I have read that I need to use the `Popen.returncode`, but how I can get it to actively check the state, I don't know.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

<strike>Both [`wait()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.wait) (with `timeout` specified) and [`poll()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.poll) return `None` if the process has not yet finished, and something different if the process *has* finished (I think an integer, the exit code, hopefully 0).</strike>

**Edit**:

[`wait()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.wait) and [`poll()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.poll) have different behaviors:

- `wait` (without the timeout argument) will block and wait for the process to complete.
- `wait` with the timeout argument will wait `timeout` seconds for the process to complete.  If it doesn't complete, it will throw the `TimeoutExpired` exception.  If you catch the exception, you're then welcome to go on, or to `wait` again.
- `poll` always returns immediately.  It effectively does a wait with a timeout of 0, catches any exception, and returns `None` if the process hasn't completed.
- With either `wait` or `poll`, if the process has completed, the popen object's [`returncode`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.returncode) will be set (otherwise it's None - you can check for that as easily as calling `wait` or `poll`), and the return value from the function will also be the process's return code.

**</Edit>**

So I think you should do something like:

```
while myprocess.poll() is None:
    print("Still working...")
    # sleep a while
```

Be aware that if the bash script creates a lot of output you must use `communicate()` or something similar to prevent *stdout* or *stderr* to become stuffed.

Comment: I am using communicate(). But I don't get it as to how I can return the returncode while the process is being executed.

Comment: I solved it by doing this: if process.poll() is None: print 'Working'

Comment: If _stdout_ and _stderr_ becoming stuffed is a concern, and/or to pass that info to the user while running, do `for line in myprocess.stdout: print(line)` and `for line in myprocess.stderr: print(line, file=sys.stderr)` (or something similar) once a loop. Careful, though, as the reads are blocking.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, as of my edit on May 31 '16, this answer is no longer incorrect.  (I still upvoted @onlyone for catching the mistakes.)

Answer (score 33):

@extraneon's answer is a little backwards. Both `wait()` and `poll()` return the process's exit code if the process has finished. The `poll()` method will return `None` if the process is still running and the `wait()` method will block until the process exits:

Check out the following page: https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/subprocess.html#popen-objects

`Popen.poll()`

> Check if child process has terminated. Set and return returncode attribute.

`Popen.wait()`

> Wait for child process to terminate. Set and return returncode attribute.

Comment: Anyone coming to experimenting with this `Popen.poll()` for the first time needs to be a bit wary of using "truthy" values: if you do `if popen.poll():` and your child process has returned 0, this will be `False`, i.e. it will look like the child process has not completed when it has. Better to test with `if popen.poll()!=None:`.